# Blade Syntax Error with empty string variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have this input:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="nameEng" name="nameEng" value="{{$tagTrans['en']}}" />
```

And if the variable is empty I got this message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''); ?>">' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

If it isn't empty everything is perfect.

What is the problem?

**EDIT:** My Controller@Action is:

```
public function newTag($id = 0){

    $tag = array();
    $tagTrans = array();

    if ($id > 0){
        $tag = Tags::where(['id' => $id])
                        -> first()
                        -> toArray();

        $tagTransRaw = TagTrans::where(
                                ['tag_id' => $id ])
                            ->get()
                            ->toArray();

        foreach ($tagTransRaw as $key => $tagTransFE) {
            $tagTrans[$tagTransFE['lang']] = $tagTransFE['text'];
        }  
    }

    $data = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'tag' => $tag,
            'tagTrans' => $tagTrans,
        );

    return view('back/news/newTag', $data);
}
```

**EDIT2:**
Tried other methods:

```
 - value="{{$tagTrans['en'] or ''}}"
 - value="{{
   !empty($tagTrans['en'])? $tagTrans['en'] : '' }}"
```

They didn't worked.

**EDIT3:**
I deleted the `value="..."`-s in the form to show the `var_dump($data)`, what @Mr. Pyramid asked, and now it shows the same error on the end of the file (when it renders the blade templates).

I now thinking about that it's a `composer update` error what I ran a few hours ago. I checked in git that the updated packages was these:

```
package name
version from
version to

"name": "laravel/framework", 
"version": "v5.5.19", 
"version": "v5.5.20", 

"name": "nikic/php-parser", 
"version": "v3.1.1", 
"version": "v3.1.2",

"name": "psy/psysh", 
"version": "v0.8.13", 
"version": "v0.8.14", 

"name": "doctrine/instantiator", 
"version": "1.0.5", 
"version": "1.1.0", 

"name": "phpunit/php-code-coverage", 
"version": "5.2.2", 
"version": "5.2.3",

"name": "phpunit/phpunit", 
"version": "6.4.3", 
"version": "6.4.4", 

"name": "sebastian/comparator", 
"version": "2.0.2", 
"version": "2.1.0",
```

**EDIT4:**

I tinkered with my code, but the problem is the same.
`var_dump($data):`

```
$data = array(
 "id" => 0
  "tag" => []
  "tagTrans" => []
);
```

The input is now this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="nameEng" name="nameEng" value="{{ array_key_exists('en', $tagTrans) ? $tagTrans['en'] : '' }}" />
```

Comment: I assume the error is being thrown via the controller therefore we need to see that code too.

Comment: @Option Whoops shows this line as the base of the error. I edited the question with the Controller Action

Comment: please show your `dd($data)` or `var_dump($data)`

Comment: if you use php7 - {{ $tagTrans['en'] ?? '' }}, if 5.6 - {{ !empty$tagTrans['en'] ?: '' }}

Comment: I found something that it isn't an error about the variables. It's an error about rendering the blade.php. I updated my question with EDIT3

Comment: Are you returning this variable `$tagTrans` to the view? Because I don't see it in your controller.

Comment: Pleas do a `dd($data);` right before `return view('back/news/newTag', $data);`

Comment: @mazedlx I updated my question, with EDIT4

Comment: I found out the error: One of the input's I had a bonus '

Comment: That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. Some rows upper I had this:

`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$id'}}">`

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the key exists in the array using [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="nameEng" name="nameEng" 
 value="{{ array_key_exists('en', $tagTrans) ? $tagTrans['en'] : '' }}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found something that it isn't an error about the variables. It's an error about rendering the blade.php. I updated my question with EDIT3

Answer (score 1):

I guess the array data does not contain the key 'en'.

You can try this :
`value="{{$tagTrans['en'] or ''}}"`

Good luck.

Comment: I tried `value="{{$tagTrans['en'] or ''}}"` and `value="{{ !empty($tagTrans['en'])? $tagTrans['en'] : '' }}"` , too, without any success.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
{{ empty($tagTrans['en']) ? '' : $tagTrans['en'] }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found something that it isn't an error about the variables. It's an error about rendering the blade.php. I updated my question with EDIT3